# What causes Android to have slow WiFi performance?

Tags: wi-fi

I have a Samsung Galaxy SII (GT-I9100 with Android 4.0.3) and a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1(GT-P7500 on Android 4.0.4). They both perform awfully slow on WiFi for internet related Apps.

Either Facebook, YouTube, Any web browser (Chrome, Mozilla, Dolphin and native) perform like if the WiFi connection was a slow one. Frequent time-outs in Play Store, videos taking forever to buffer, etc.

I Know for sure that at least at home the router/modem is not the issue, as I can have two laptops running Windows consumming WiFi at normal speeds, i.e. each one streaming a video on YouTube without pauses for buffering, but at the same time, one of my androids woul not even be capable of playing the same video, or take, say 1 minute to load a page that on my laptop loads in 2-3 seconds. The same happens in other WiFi Networks I connect them to. My devices have developed this behavior from 10-8 months ago and it has slowly worsened over time,

Is this something related to the Android Operating system? Could it be one of my apps? And if it is one of the apps, how can I identify and kill it?

It does not seem to be a disconnecting from network problem, I get steady connection indicator.

Note: I consider myself almost a lean user: I don´t keep a lot of apps and dont usually leave running the ones I use (i.e. I close the browsers, the facebook app, etc, and constantly check whether apps are running with the app manager).

Note 2: These devices sometimes work faster on 3G, wich doesn't make much sense because here in my country the provider is not very good and many of the cell towers(antenas) are clogged with a too many users. In these cases I normally get the normal, expected lag of such network.